# Cannot Input Accented Characters Into WPF TextBox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm writing a WPF app to do Italian Vocabulary Drills.

When I try to enter an accented char using the Windows keyboard shortcuts it's only appearing in the text box as the underlying char.

For instance - CTRL at the same time as the ` and then i just gives me the i - it does not place the accent on top.

Here's the XAML

`<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Text="English" Name ="EnglishWord" Width="auto" FontSize="72"/>`

It does give me the accented char in Word and WordPad so I don't think it's a Windows level setting.

FULL XAMAL

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="" Margin="191,125,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" Width="473" Height="99"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

AppCS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce (using french characters but it guess it's the same context) https://i.imgur.com/9TNtILw.png Can you provide a fully reproducing project https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As you can see the problem happens even with a nearly blank project. What keyboard shortcuts are you using to create the accented chars. Or, what languages and keyboards do you have installed. I'm using these instructions to create the chars - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-to-add-language-accent-marks-in-word-and-outlook-3801b103-6a8d-42a5-b8ba-fdc3774cfc76

Comment: Ok, so it's about some special accent marks, alright. So based on the document you sent, I'm thinking it must be some specific behavior for the apps mentioned in the header of the article so _Word for Microsoft 365 Outlook for Microsoft 365 Word 2021 Outlook 2021 Word 2019 Outlook 2019 Word 2016 Outlook 2016 Word 2013 Outlook 2013 Word 2010_. I've tested it in the Word and indeed i got accented mark, but for example on Notepad it does not work. So in order to have this accented mark on your textbox you need to implement it yourself. Please find my anwer to that.

Answer (score 1):

So firstly you need to capture that *ACCENT GRAVE* has been hit on the keyboard.

You can do it like that

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Oem3 && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        _accentGravePressed = true; 
    }
}
```

Note that this accent grave character can be linked to different `Key` enum, base on your keyboard. On mine it's `Oem3`.

Then in order to actaully add the accent to the char in the TextBox, you can do something like this

```
private void txtBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    if (_accentGravePressed )
    {
        var accented = e.Text;
        accented += "\u0301";
        txtBox.Text += accented.Normalize();
        txtBox.CaretIndex = txtBox.Text.Length;

        _accentGravePressed = false;
        e.Handled = true;   
    }
}
```

Comment: I hate this answer because it's going to be messy - but I think it's the correct one. It's going to take me a couple of weeks to get around to coding it so I'll mark it as correct and hand over the 50.